# The for loop does not end only at a declared function, not main

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator

**My question is the for loop is does not end at a particular situation.**

I wrote the code below

I intend the for loop at `find_period` is ended when `iter` meet `arr.end()`

But it didn't.

```cpp
int find_period(vector<int> arr){
    vector<int>::iterator iter;
    for(iter=arr.begin(); iter != arr.end(); iter++){
        cout << *iter << endl;
    }
}
```

But when I moved the for loop to the `main()`, it worked properly.

```cpp
int main() {
    vector<int> input = {2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    vector<int>::iterator iter;

    //for(iter=input.begin(); iter != input.end(); iter++){
    //  cout << *iter << endl;
    ///}

    cout << find_period(input) << endl;
}

I don't know why this thing happens.

At first, I think it is related with the concept of pointer. Therefore, I modified the code that use pointer `int find_period(vector<int> *arr)`. But it didn't work too.

Could you give me a little hint?

Thanks a lot!
```

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything

Comment: @ThomasSablik Yes, you are right. However it doesn’t affect the result, I think.

Comment: Doing that is undefined behavior. That means it could affect the result.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Sorry. You're right. When I added return line, it works properly!

Comment: @Chipster Yes. As you said, it affects the result! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your first program just printed numbers from the `vector`, but now you want the loop to be in a function, then you should just call the function:

```
void print_vector(const vector<int>& arr){
    for(auto item: arr){
        cout << item << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<int> input = {2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    print_vector(input);
}
```

Initially I was confused when you said: `I intend the for loop at find_period is ended when iter meet arr.end(). But it didn't.`

Now I think what is happening is that your function `find_period()` does indeed print all the numbers and stop at the last, but your call: `cout << find_period(input) << endl;` prints an additional `0`, so I'm sure you were seeing:

```
...
7
8
9
0
```

Comment: I appreciate you! I deeply understand it.

Comment: But when I deleted cout <<, <<endl in the main, it shows unexpected results. When adding return line, it works properly!

Comment: I can't tell what you mean by unexpected results.

Comment: when there is no 'return 0;' in the `main` and `find_period`, it shows the unexpected number continuously. For example, it shows 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 909670440 299125235 1469 9639840 and so on. As you teach me, "cout << find_period(input) << endl" is also the cause of the unexpected result because it shows 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 '0'.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
cout << find_period(input) << endl;
```

prints the return value of

```
find_period
```

but

```
find_period
```

doesn't return anything. That's undefined behaviour. Remove the last output:

```
find_period(input);
```

instead of

```
cout << find_period(input) << endl;
```

Comment: It helps me many things. In addition to your lesson, adding a return line makes my code work properly! Thank you so much!